# How to use Tab layout with the data binding library and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout, android-databinding

I'm trying to use Tab Layout + Android Data Binding Library in a Kotlin project, but I'm not succeeding.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is mine Activity:

```
class WoActivity : BaseActivity()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_wo) as ActivityWoBinding

        binding.wo = WorkOrder()

        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        binding.setHandler(this);
        binding.setManager(getSupportFragmentManager());

    }

    companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("handler") @JvmStatic
        fun bindViewPagerAdapter(view: ViewPager, activity: WoActivity) {
            val adapter = WOPagerAdapter(activity.supportFragmentManager)
            adapter.addFragment(WoTabWoFragment.newInstance(), view.context.getString(R.string.work_order))
            adapter.addFragment(WoTabScheFragment.newInstance(), view.context.getString(R.string.scheduling))
            view.adapter = adapter
        }

        @BindingAdapter("pager") @JvmStatic
        fun bindViewPagerTabs(view: TabLayout, pagerView: ViewPager) {
            view.setupWithViewPager(pagerView, true)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the final result: A empty tab without touch effects
[image]

Comment: would be good if you included your layout xml as well.